# What can I use instead of the :indeterminate jQuery selector to avoid an exception in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have code like this

```
if ($('#chkCheckAll').is(':indeterminate') == true) 
{
}
```

But it is throwing exception in  ie 8

what can do instead of this in Jquery to work with ie8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var $allChk = $('#chkCheckAll');
if ($allChk[0] && $allChk[0].indeterminate ) {
  ... 
}
```

The problem is that ':indeterminate' pseudo-expression is not supported by IE8 `querySelectorAll` implementation. But in your case, it's actually not required to use it, as you can query the corresponding property of DOM element itself

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great article http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

It SORT of works IE8 using .prop and has a [hack](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/mGg85/2/) too

```
<!-- Ghetto click handler -->
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="ts(this)">function ts(cb) {
  if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked=cb.readOnly=false;
  else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly=cb.indeterminate=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancement of Ghetto handler to include the data in form submission:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .nodisplay {display: none;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function ts(cb) {
                if (cb.readOnly) 
                    cb.nextSibling.checked 
                    = cb.checked
                    = cb.readOnly
                    = false;
                else if (!cb.checked) 
                    cb.nextSibling.checked 
                    = cb.readOnly
                    = cb.indeterminate=true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" onclick="ts(this)"
            ><input type="checkbox" name="cb1i" />

            <input type="submit">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is either nothing (unchecked) cb1=on (checked) or cb1i=on (indeterminate).  Note that for nextSibling to work in this case there must be no whitespace between the two checkboxes, otherwise it'll give you a text node.