# How to get clicked indeterminate checkboxes to 'checked' state

Tags: jquery

I have tried to follow this thread that suggests a solution to [check indeterminate states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625719/what-can-i-use-instead-of-the-indeterminate-jquery-selector-to-avoid-an-excepti).

I am using ASP.NET, and it seems that clicking a checkbox in indeterminate state will uncheck it, and not fire any event (the underlying checkbox is actually 'unchecked'). I was thinking of having Javascript check it for me when I click a checkbox that is in indeterminate state (prefer the logic this way, and that should fire my ASP.NET event).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".UndefinedCheckboxState :checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true);

    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("indeterminate")) {
            $(this).prop("indeterminate", false);
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** The click event works fine, but the condition in the `if` is never true ! I keep clicking checkboxes in indeterminate state though...

Comment: OT: `$(this)[0] === this` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused, posted an answer, but it seems the checkboxes gets checked when I click them, even without any javascript, and the change event is always triggered -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Dj9/2/), so I'm not getting the same result you are at all ?

Comment: I've actually tried your thing, I see now that in IE the default behavior is indeterminate to unchecked, and the opposite for chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that if the checkbox that was clicked has an indeterminate state, by the first instruction within the click event, that property has gone already.

I have replaced my logic to test something that has not faded away yet :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".UndefinedCheckboxState :checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true);

        $(":checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).closest("span").hasClass("UndefinedCheckboxState")) {
                $(this).prop("indeterminate", false);
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending @adeneo's answer, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".UndefinedCheckboxState input[type='checkbox']").prop("indeterminate", true);

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
        console.log('changed');
        console.log('current value: '+$(this).prop('checked') );  
    });
});
```

View on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Dj9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `is()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".UndefinedCheckboxState :checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true);

    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":indeterminate")) {
            $(this).prop("indeterminate", false);
        }
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```